# how to add third party library to spark running on local machine

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

i am listening to eventhub stream and have seen article to attach library to cluster(databricks) and my code runs file.

For debugging i am running the code on local machine/cluster, but it fails for missing library. How can i add library when running on local machine.

i tried sparkcontext.addfile(fullpathtojar), but still same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use spark-submit --packages

*Example:* spark-submit --packages org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.1

You would need to find the package that you are using and check the compatibility with spark.

With a single jar file you'd use `spark-submit --jars` instead.

Answer (score 0):

i used spark-submit --packages {package} and it works.